# How can I reply to an answer?

Tags: support

On every stackoverflow page, I see replies by other people under each answer.
All I can figure out how to do is how to edit the answer.
How can I reply to an answer, so my reply gets printed underneath it, in smaller letters, with my username?

On this particular page, I now see there is an "add comment" link underneath that would presumably let me add a comment. But no such link appears on stackoverflow pages, neither on Chrome under Windows nor on Firefox under CentOS.

Comment: You need 50 reputation to comment http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: If you login with a google account, you automatically get 100 in rep, so if you login with a google o(or FB) account then you can comment right away on any of these sites.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz What gives you that idea? As far as I know that's incorrect. Unless you're confusing your association bonus, which has nothing to do with those IDs, but with the reputation you've earned on another account. (200 rep afaik)